# My Joomla website won't render in Facebook's in-app Android browser

Tags: android, facebook, joomla3.0

[This website](https://www.luzzattolaw.co.il) won't render at all in Facebook's in-app Android browser. Works fine on the desktop, mobile, Apple's in-app FB browser, but on Android - nothing. I just get a gray, empty screen with the URL in the URL window - no error message or other indicators that something is wrong.

After lots of cache-cleaning within the Facebook app (including even an install-reinstall of the entire Facebook app), I reposted using the bityl link shortener and this appeared to work in some of the Android phones I tested.

There is a real dearth of information on this subject, so any ideas anyone has are welcome.

I found here and there a few responses suggesting that this might be related to non-secure content. I checked using this tool - https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/ and didn't find any insecure content anywhere on the website.

Thanks.

Comment: That in-app browser is a sickness, I don’t know of any way to properly debug in there - especially in a case where you get nothing _at all_ showing. I’d perhaps start by checking the server access log (filter it by User Agent maybe) and see if any resources that the page should request, don’t get requested by the in-app browser. And also the error log, to see if any resources produce a 500 or something, when requested by that thing. Good luck ;-)

Comment: @misorude - thank you. Yes, it is indeed challenging. I will check the error log.